# CSS - Setting padding/margins based on text-width?

Tags: css

Is there a measuring unit in CSS (either planned or already in existence) for setting the padding and margins based on the width of the font being used?

I know that `em` is supposed to be the height of the upper-case M of the font the browser uses, which is really handy for adding a clean double-spacing. But I sometimes want the side-margins of inline lists to be the width of a normal non-breaking space, or the width of an upper-case A. With some fonts, using em is vary unreliable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Funny, but it [seems that nobody cares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface#Font_metrics) about width of typeface elements. Everything that's measured, is the height:

[image]

If this is the case in "classical typography", then there is even less hope in web typography which is a subclass of the former.

EDIT: Actually there is a [measurement named En](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_(typography)) which refers to " width of a lowercase letter "n"." However, I haven't seen this used in web.

Comment: This is especially odd, I think, since typesetting spends a lot of time on the topic of leading, kerning, word-spacing, letter-spacing,etc, which all seem to deal with how letters are layed out vertically. You'd think at least one of these would have evolved a "distance of actual character-width".

Comment: I see in the Wikipedia article you refer to that **en** is defined as half of 1 em, which means that you can use `0.5em` instead of `1en` (I don't think *en* is supported as unit in css). The article says that *it is also traditionally the width of a lowercase letter "n"*.

Comment: As a side note: The reason why "nobody seems to care" about the width of typeface elements, is that the characters have different widths within a font (unless it is a monospace font). This means that the width is not a common property on the font, but on each character within the font.

Answer (score 9):

The W3C specifications for css3 defines a unit that is the width of the font's "0" character:

> **ch unit**
>
> Equal to the used advance measure of the "0" (ZERO, U+0030) glyph found in the font used to render it.

See [css3-values](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#relative-lengths).

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid no. CSS does not offer a way to reference fonts properties.

But you can always get away by inserting `&nbsp;` in the extra first and last list elements.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with something simple that helped me with a padding issue based on font size. I wanted to offset a `<td>` based on a string prefix in the row above. Cliff notes version, I add the text that represents the desired offset in a span and make it invisible and unselectable. My solution is here:

```
.hiddenOffset {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
cursor: default;
}


<table>
  <tr>
    <td>NumElements</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="hiddenOffset">Num</span>Offset Text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This gives me the perfect offset and the prefix is hidden and non-selectable. In my actual code I use pure JavaScript to specify the prefix string so it's not hardcoded and I use `prefix.repeat(n)` to set nested indentations.

```
function processRepeatingGroupInstance(indent, group) {
    let prefix = 'No';
    let html = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
        let field = group[i];
        if (field.hasOwnProperty('msgvaluedesc'))
            html += `<tr><td><span class="hiddenOffset">${prefix.repeat(indent)}</span>${field.name}</td><td class="num">${field.number}</td><td class="value tooltip">${field.msgvaluedesc}<span class="tooltiptext">${field.msgvalue}</span></td></tr>`;
        else
            html += `<tr><td><span class="hiddenOffset">${prefix.repeat(indent)}</span>${field.name}</td><td class="num">${field.number}</td><td class="value">${field.msgvalue}</td></tr>`;
        if (field.hasOwnProperty('repeating_group')) {
            for (let j = 0; j < field.repeating_group.length; j++)
                html += processRepeatingGroupInstance(indent + 1, field.repeating_group[j]);
        }
    }
    return html;
}
```

[image: Results]